# Using a button instead a confirm box with javascript within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a loop, in javascript

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   var j = i
   var k = confirm("continue?")
   if (k) {continue}
      else {break}
   }
alert(j)
```

But instead using a confirm box 'confirm' I want to use a `<button>`, like :

```
        for (var i=0;i<10;) {
            var j = i;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#button").click(function() {i++})
                    $("#exit").click(function() {break})
                })
          }
       alert(j)
```

This sample doesn't work
How I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand what your asking..

Comment: i++0 ... Please correct your code and make your question clearer.

Comment: If you expect jQuery answers you should add the jquery Tag aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a for loop that relies on user input to go to the next step of the loop if you don't pause the for loop to wait for the input. That's what the `confirm()` function does, it pauses the execution of the for loop. In your second example, you are no longer pausing the execution of the for loop but instead creating 10 `onClick` functions for each of the two buttons.

If you want to have the user click a button to continue execution of a for loop, you can no longer create a traditional for loop since you can't pause execution this way. Instead, you'll have to create a mock for loop that allows for user input to continue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var length = 10;

  function step() {
    if (i >= length) {
      terminate();
    }
  }

  function terminate() {
    alert(i);
  }

  $('#button').click(function() {
    step(++i);
  });
  $('#exit').click(function() {
    terminate();
    $('#button').off('click');
    $('#exit').off('click');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was searching for